# What happens if you never call Socket.EndConnect?

Tags: .net, sockets

Using .Net 4.0. I have a some code which tries to open a connection using BeginConnect and a callback. If the user tries to stop the programming in the next few moments I try to disconnect. At that point I set a flag to indicate whether or not the EndConnect needs to be called from the callback. If the flag is set to false I skip the EndConnect because the socket has been trashed anyway.

At this point the user can try connect again immediately. I don't see this happening but just in case. Now a new socket is created and BeginConnect is called again.

Is it fine to never call the EndConnect method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all cases (except one<sup>[1]</sup>) a call to `BeginZZZ` needs a matching `EndZZZZ`.

Otherwise non-managed resources are going to be leaked, and quite possibly the action `ZZZZ` will not correctly complete—potentially corrupting further uses of `ZZZZ` later.

Sockets are pretty robust against abuse (the IP stack has to handle network failures and packets out of order), but that doesn't make it good practice.

If you are using a flag to track "shutting down", better to call [`EndConnect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.endconnect.aspx) and then close the socket immediately. After all the connect could itself fail, and a disconnect not needed (`EndConnect` throws [`SocketException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception.aspx)). Something like:

```
mySocket.BeginConnect(address, port, ia => {
  if (shuttingDown) {
    try {
      mySocket.EndConnect(ia);
      mySocket.BeginDisconnect(false, iaa = {
        try {
          mySocket.EndDisconnect(iaa);
        } catch (Exception) { /* Ignore */ }
      }, null);
    } catch (SocketException) { /* Ignore */ }
  } else {
    // Normal connection handling
  }
}, null);
```

Also using async disconnect to avoid blocking there.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> The Exception is [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx) in WinForms, where the exception is explicitly documented.

Comment: @Richard. Thanks for the response. I tried your approach but I keep getting exceptions about the AsyncResult not being the same from the corresponding begin call. I came across some guy's blog which says that we should cache the AsyncResult and check if it is the same before we do anything. This seems dodgy and leaves me back at the starting point anyway. Just ignoring the thing.

Comment: @Richard. Okay wow. The MSDN is very wishy washy on a couple of things. First it states: You can create a callback method that implements the AsyncCallback delegate and pass its name to the BeginConnect method. Which really sounds like it is optional. Then the next paragraphs states: Your callback method should invoke the EndConnect method. They just told me that it is optional now they are telling me that I should call EndConnect. I can't call EndConnect if I "optionally" left it out. However: This part gave me hope: To cancel a pending call to the BeginConnect method, close the Socket.

Comment: @uriDium: The callback is optional, but calling `EndConnect` isn't. Instead you can wait on the `IAsyncResult` returned from `BeginConnect` (or poll its `IsCompleted` property) and then call `EndConnect` -- all without using the callback. Summary: `EndConnect` has to be called, but this doesn't need to be inside the delegate passed to `BeginConnect`.

Comment: @uriDium: Re exception for wrong `AsyncResult`: Are you sure you have the right `Socket` instance... you need to be careful to stick with the same socket. If using a field (or variable outside a loop) you might have the wrong socket instance. My code sample assumes `mySocket` is a local variable that is only ever used for a single reference (so not a loop variable over a collection).

Comment: @Richard. Yip pretty sure. I pass in the socket in the state. I use that object to EndConnect. I then also call BeginDisconnect on that same object once again passing in the same socket into the state. Then in the Callback method I call EndDisconnect on that socket from the AsyncState and I get that exception. Maybe I need to look harder. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @uriDium: To track whether you have the same objects you can use VS's "Get Object Id" debugger feature: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/120011/How-to-track-an-object-which-is-Out-of-Scope-while.aspx

Comment: Another case when EndZZZ cause documented excpetion:

"To cancel a pending call to the BeginAccept method, close the Socket. When the Close method is called while an asynchronous operation is in progress, the callback provided to the BeginAccept method is called. A subsequent call to the EndAccept method will throw an ObjectDisposedException to indicate that the operation has been cancelled."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bb431f9.aspx